# NDSove vs ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

`ParametricNDSolve` is very practical when one has to execute `NDSolve` again and again. However is it equally accurate? I have not yet found how `ParametricNDSolve` exactly works and I hesitate use it instead of `NDSolve` in my code.

Comment: They both act as front doors to the same complex of algorithms for solving ODEs and PDEs. So they're just as accurate as each other if they call the same algorithms. `ParametricNDSolve` does things automatically, and the only drawback I recall is that with the shooting method, you might need to tweak `"StartingInitialConditions"` depending on the parameters, and you can't do that with `ParametericNDSolve`. There are probably other such edge cases.

Comment: To piggyback on the question, does it give a speedup over using just `NDSolve`, aside from the fact that it caches the results?

Comment: Well, poking around for something else, I accidentally came across this relevant innovation.  One can use [`InitialSeeding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InitialSeeding.html) in V12 with `ParametricNDSolve` to give starting points for the shooting method (there's an example in the docs).  However, it uses FEM as a solver.

Comment: @KraZug Yes, apparently: `psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[x] == k y[x], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 1}, {k}];
Table[psol[kk/100], {kk, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming // Print;
Table[NDSolve[{y'[x] == k/100 y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}], {k, 
      1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming // Print;`

Comment: @MichaelE2, presumably mostly because it doesn't have to do the overhead of setting up the differential equations each time, it has done it once in advance.